# SQL Filter unique results

Tags: sql

I am trying to get an SQL statement that will output a unique part number eg no duplicates
However I want the type as Purchased is the default and when there isnt a Purchased part it defults back to Manufactured.  NOTE all parts can be purchased

The result I require is to only show unique part numbers
e.g. 1 to 10 and Purchased is the default Type

Table1

```
Part_number | Type         | Cost
Part 1 |    Manufactured   | £1.00
Part 1 |    Purchased      | £0.56
Part 2 |    Manufactured   | £1.26
Part 2 |    Purchased      | £0.94
Part 3 |    Manufactured   | £0.36
Part 3 |    Purchased      | £0.16
Part 4 |    Manufactured   | £1.00 
Part 4 |    Purchased      | £1.50
Part 5 |    Manufactured   | £1.65
Part 6 |    Manufactured   | £1.98 
Part 7 |    Manufactured   | £0.15
Part 8 |    Manufactured   | £0.45
Part 9 |    Manufactured   | £1.20
Part 9 |    Purchased      | £0.80
Part 10|    Manufactured   | £1.00
```

This is the result I am hoping to get back

```
Part_number | Type         | Cost
Part 1 |    Purchased      | £0.56
Part 2 |    Purchased      | £0.94
Part 3 |    Purchased      | £0.16
Part 4 |    Purchased      | £1.50
Part 5 |    Manufactured   | £1.65
Part 6 |    Manufactured   | £1.98 
Part 7 |    Manufactured   | £0.15
Part 8 |    Manufactured   | £0.45
Part 9 |    Purchased      | £0.80
Part 10|    Manufactured   | £1.00
```

I have tried loads of different techniques but am not getting the result.

I am guessing that I will need to create temp tables that are filtered and then join the tables together but I really don't know.

Any help will be apricated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also just grab the first row in each group by sorting them. This would make it easier when there are other columns of data to bring back.

```
with data as (
    select *, row_number() over (
        partition by part_number
        order by case when t.type = Purchased then 1 else 2 end) as rn
    from t
)
select * from data where rn = 1;
```

If there are other types this would work as well although you would want to tweak it if there are more than two per part.

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `not exists`.  Assuming you have at most two rows per part:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.type = 'Purchased' or
      (t.type = 'Manufactured' and
       not (exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.part_number = t.part_number and t2.type = 'Purchased')
           )
      );
```

There are other fun ways to handle this.  For instance, an aggregation approach:

```
select part_number,
       max(type) as type,
       coalesce(max(case when type = 'Purchased' then cost end),,
                max(cost)
               ) as cost
from t
group by part_number;
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help the second method worked for me.